# How to present a ViewController as a Modal Sheet without the background shadow

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there any way to present a ViewController as a Modal Sheet without the background shadow as shown in the first image below using swift. Is there an easy way or should we need to write custom UIPresentationController? [![The required output][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAEEn.png![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAEEn.png!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4JD5.jpg)

Comment: You can create a View & then show it with animation.

Comment: That's a new feature in iOS 15: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3858107-largestundimmeddetentidentifier

Comment: @Imran0001 Is there any other way without using view. Because I need these kind of view controller presentations in other places too. So this can be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @matt I know about this feature but this is only available from iOS 15 right ??

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'll have to use some other way of presenting the view controller, such as `.overCurrentContext`, and/or write your own custom view controller presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smaller size view controller as per your need. Firstly add a class.

```
class SmallSizePresentationController : UIPresentationController {
        override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
            get {
                guard let theView = containerView else {
                    return CGRect.zero
                }
                return CGRect(x: 0, y: theView.bounds.height * (281 / 896), width: theView.bounds.width, height: theView.bounds.height)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Then when you want to present this type of view controller just add the extension of your current view controller.**

```
extension YourCurrentViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return SmallSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
}
```

**Then present your new view controller like this**

```
let VC = withoutShadowVC()
VC.transitioningDelegate = self
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**You can modify the view controller height.**